# Determining the most relevant keyword in a body of text

Tags: javascript, nlp

Given a body of text and several keywords I want to determine which keyword is the most relevant. So I basically want to see which keyword occurs the most times but it’s a bit more complex than that because I want to search keywords in both their plural and non-plural forms and remove generic words like "and" and "the".

I could write a function to do a decent job at this but rather than reinventing the wheel I’m wondering if there’s a good nlp library, ideally in JS, that handles this sort of thing i.e., keyword relevance. Accuracy is more important than performance in this case but both are important.

To give a specific example of what this will be used for, of the three keywords highlighted in yellow at the top, "disney" should come out as most relevant as it occurs in the article the most number of times and is most specific to the article. https://www.guide.com/gift-guide-for-all-the-disney-fanatics-in-your-life/a

Comment: [Search for NLP in NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=nlp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural is a good library for natural language processing. https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural. There is a good free course on it here https://egghead.io/courses/natural-language-processing-in-javascript-with-natural.